# Twitter Typeahead.js with Yahoo Finance in AJAX

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I am trying to couple the new version of [Typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) and using it with JSON that needs to be pulled from AJAX and not from a JSON file like they have in their examples. I just can't get it to work, I don't want to cache the JSON result or anything, I want to pull it live from Yahoo.

My HTML input is `<input type="text" id="symbol" name="symbol" autofocus autocomplete="off" placeholder="Symbol" onkeyup="onSymbolChange(this.value)"  />`

My AJAX/PHP file has this to retrieve data (this part work, I tested it with Firebug)

```php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8;');

$action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : null;
$symbol = (isset($_GET['symbol'])) ? $_GET['symbol'] : null;

switch($action) {
    case 'autocjson':
        getYahooSymbolAutoComplete($symbol);
        break;
}

function getYahooSymbolAutoCompleteJson($symbolChar) {
    $data = @file_get_contents("http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?callback=YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks&query=$symbolChar");

    // parse yahoo data into a list of symbols
    $result = [];
    $json = json_decode(substr($data, strlen('YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks('), -1));

    foreach ($json->ResultSet->Result as $stock) {
        $result[] = '('.$stock->symbol.') '.$stock->name;
    }

    echo json_encode(['symbols' => $result]);
}
```

The JS file (this is where I'm struggling)

```js
function onSymbolChange(symbolChar) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yahoo_autocomplete_ajax.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'autocjson',
            symbol: symbolChar
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#symbol').typeahead({
                name: 'symbol',
                remote: response.symbols
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I don't think that I'm suppose to attach a typeahead inside an AJAX success response, but I don't see much examples with AJAX (except for a previous version of typeahead)... I see the JSON response with Firebug after typing a character but the input doesn't react so good. Any guidance would really be appreciated, I'm working on a proof of concept at this point... It's also worth to know that I'm using AJAX because I am in HTTPS and using a direct http to Yahoo API is giving all kind of problems with Chrome and new Firefox for insecure page.

**UPDATE**

To make it to work, thanks to Hieu Nguyen, I had to modify the AJAX JSON response from this `echo json_encode(['symbols' => $result]);` to instead this `echo json_encode($result);` and modify the JS file to use the code as suggested here:

```js
$('#symbol').typeahead({
    name: 'symbol',
    remote: 'yahoo_autocomplete_ajax.php?action=autocjson&symbol=%QUERY'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to do it in reverse, i.e: hook the ajax call inside typeahead `remote` handler. You can try:

```js
$('#symbol').typeahead({
    name: 'symbol',
    remote: '/yahoo_autocomplete_ajax.php?action=autocjson&symbol=%QUERY'
});
```

You don't have to create `onSymbolChange()` function since typeahead will take care of that already.

You can also filter and debug the response from backend by using:

```js
$('#symbol').typeahead({
    name: 'symbol',
    remote: {
        url: '/yahoo_autocomplete_ajax.php?action=autocjson&symbol=%QUERY',
        filter: function(resp) {
            var dataset = [];
            console.log(resp); // debug the response here

            // do some filtering if needed with the response          

            return dataset;
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did it the way you said and it's not fully working just yet, I always get "undefined" as the only possible choice displaying but I do see the JSON response in Firebug, is my JSON format proper?

Comment: Thanks it does help, I was wondering where did you get that information or being able to use the url and filter and so on? I would like to use their template at the end but I'm not there yet... BTW I was returning a JSON array of Symbols: `{"symbols":["(GOOG)...", "(GO..."]...}` but instead I have to pass an array format so after scrapping the `symbols` object it worked. Thanks

Comment: I have been answering questions about typeahead.js on SO for a while so I can remember this details. You can see the docs here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#remote